# in java how to copy data from file in the URL into excel worksheet

Tags: java, networking, urlconnection

i am working on a system and need to fetch file from the URL using java URLConnection, Now all i need to copy that contents into excel file. 
        here is my code.

```
class getsize {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        try {

            String plainCreds = "hmhinstall:hmh201208";
            //          String url = "http://content.link-systems.com/~hbern/content_update/";
            byte[] plainCredsBytes = plainCreds.getBytes();
            String base64CredsBytes = Base64.encode(plainCredsBytes);
            String base64Creds = base64CredsBytes;
            System.out.println(base64Creds);
            int code = 0;

            URL url = new URL("http://content.link-systems.com/~hbern/content_update/ ");
//Reading
            URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    uc.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(inputLine);    //Printing file data
}
            in.close();

//Getting size

            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            System.out.println(conn.getResponseCode());
            System.out.println(conn.getContentType());

            conn.getInputStream();
            System.out.println("Length : " + conn.getContentLength()); //Getting content length

        } catch (Exception exception) {
        } finally {
            conn.disconnect(); //Disconnect
        }

    }
}
```

How can i copy contents of a file in to excel worksheet? So that i can generate records automatically.
thanks in advance

Comment: try using Apache POI

Comment: thanks.. m trying java excel api  'jxl.jar'. how is it?

Comment: I have never heard of it.  If you a specific question about `jxl` then tag you question with jxl and show your code that you are having trouble with.

Comment: ok sir.. allright.. :)